# How can I use the AttributeRewriter to cache inline css background images using Cloudflare workers?

Tags: shopify, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I'm using a worker in Cloudflare to rewrite attributes for caching

```
const OLD_URL = 'cdn.MYDOMAIN.com';
const NEW_URL = 'cdn-uk.MYDOMAIN.com';
class AttributeRewriter {
  constructor(attributeName) {
    this.attributeName = attributeName
  }

  element(element) {
    const attribute = element.getAttribute(this.attributeName)
    if (attribute) {
      element.setAttribute(
        this.attributeName,
        attribute.replace(OLD_URL,NEW_URL),
      )
    }
  }
}

const rewriter = new HTMLRewriter()
.on('a', new AttributeRewriter('href'))
.on('img', new AttributeRewriter('src'));

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

/**
 * Respond to the request
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {
  let response = await fetch(request); 
  return rewriter.transform(response)
}
```

The problem is that I'm still seeing lots of "Non cloudflare" files using the Dr.Flare chrome extension. Inspecting these shows me that the images are being injected into inline styling in Shopify. How can I use the rewriter to ensure I catch all the images?

Comment: Sounds like you need to rewrite the CSS stylesheet, too. Unfortunately there's no CSS rewriter API, so you'd probably have to use a string replacement across the whole CSS file at once.

Comment: @KentonVarda *Sad face* thanks for your response. I'll see what I can do in terms of string replacement.